# Synchronising user data after initial login with Facebook

Tags: facebook-login

We're about to implement sign on/continue with a number of social networks. A question has arisen that I've been unable to find thoughts on/recommended best practice.

If a user updates their profile information (i.e. e-mail address) our data then becomes out of sync. Is it accepted to check and refresh the data on login/at regular intervals? That's our thinking at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use webhooks (formerly known as Realtime Updates) for that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/v2.5

Another way would be to store an Extended User Token and sync the data once in a while. Or you could sync it whenever the User hits your App again. But webhooks are definitely the best option because you can sync exactly when the change happens.